# libc.so not found error installing android x86 to usb

Tags: android, usb-drive

I am trying to install android x86 that can be run from usb. In order to install, I fallow this link:  http://www.keyables.com/2011/12/install-and-boot-android-x86-40-ice.html

I completed the installation without problem, but when I run Android x86 from BIOS boot menu, I have the error: libc.so not found CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE.

Is there anyone who have seen this error? Or can you think about what is the problem? 
Or can you suggest me another tutorial on how to run Android from usb?